# [protobuf]Are repeatedfields thread safe with embedded messages?

Tags: multithreading, protocol-buffers

In case there is a repeatedfield of message objects inside another message message, is it thread-safe to modify these objects in the following example?

```proto
message Inner_messsage{
  repeated uint32 my_array = 1;
}

message Outer_message{
  repeated Innter_message my_array_squared = 1 [packed=true];
}
```

I would think that because the tight packing, the protobuf implementation might move the data around upon an update, making the usage of the messages not thread-safe. Is this true?
Is this also true when using arenas?

Answer (score 1):

The following is written in the [C++ API](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp#google.protobuf):

> Thread-safety in the Protocol Buffer library follows a simple rule: unless explicitly >noted otherwise, it is always safe to use an object from multiple threads simultaneously >as long as the object is declared const in all threads (or, it is only used in ways that >would be allowed if it were declared const). However, if an object is accessed in one >thread in a way that would not be allowed if it were const, then it is not safe to access >that object in any other thread simultaneously.
>
> Put simply, read-only access to an object can happen in multiple threads simultaneously, >but write access can only happen in a single thread at a time.

So updating the messages are not thread-safe even for non-repeated fields.

Comment: To add to it, technically, ProtoBuf is a data exchange format. And, from the user/design perspective, it should provide the serialization/deserialization facilities. Using it in a multi-threaded context is totally up to the developer and the developer is responsible for taking care of the synchronization wherever needed.